# Can printf be hardware accelerated?

Tags: fpga, hardware

Printf is a very slow function to execute, there are variations of it that are less flexible but are faster too. Including this function in program can take quite a bit of memory. Has anyone tried to find a way to "hardware accelerate" printf so the processor can spend less time on it?

Comment: What part of printf do you think takes most of the time? Formatting? Writing to the standard output? Triggering the graphic console refresh induced by the writing? Printf triggers a lot more stuff than what you probably think it does. Benchmark both writing to the console using fwrite stdout, and using printf, and tell us the result.

Comment: Before the 1990s, it was common to have hardware to facilitate efficient IO of text to the command line, especially on computers with text-mode graphics.  Modern systems still have acceleration for parts of rendering, but the efficiency of infrequently used functions like printf is not a serious concern.

Comment: If printf is your bottleneck, you should consider a different system architecture.

Comment: Since you tagged FPGA: Xilinx has an optimized version of printf called `xil_printf`

Comment: Have you tried not using printf? Is your program faster if you don't use printf?

Comment: The printf takes several ms, it seems that the formatting part of the stdout part takes most of the time. In order to hardware accelerate, the formatting part i.e convert number to string must be done in hardware and a massive buffer be created to store the output characters. The buffer will be read at a significantly slow rate to the stdout.